# Magento hidden custom product attributes

Tags: php, magento

I am currently making a module so that users see on the checkout page something like: "People who purchased product X also purchased Y, Z and T".

I made a cronjob to calculate which are the related products for each product, and I added an attribute to products in the install script.

I decided (for simplicity) - to store the most related 5 products, so I want to store something like: `123-3-5543-1290-9911`. But I don't want the administrator to see this anywhere, and I tried the following:

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attrCode, array(
    // more stuff
    'type' => 'hidden',
    'input' => 'text',
    'visible' => 0,
    // more stuff
));
```

I looked here: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-adding-attribute-from-mysql-setup-file/ and I found some interesting stuff, but not how to completely hide this field.

The alternative would be to create my own table, but this seems to be a slightly more elegant solution.

What do you think? Is it better to create my own table, or to add an attribute and hide it?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the 'is_visible' property to 0 for catalog attributes will hide them from the admin forms in the backend, as can be seen from this code ([Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form::_setFieldset()](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php#L172)):

```
 protected function _setFieldset($attributes, $fieldset, $exclude=array())
    {
        $this->_addElementTypes($fieldset);
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
            if (!$attribute || ($attribute->hasIsVisible() && !$attribute->getIsVisible())) {
                continue;
            }
```

So execute

```
 $setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', $attrCode, 'is_visible', '0');
```

Comment: Thank you, working perfectly. Looking at the `addAttibute()` and _`setFieldset()` methods made it pretty clear.

Comment: the part that got me what that I couldn't add `is_visible` in `addAttribute`, just in update attribute. But it's things like this that make you want to kill someone. Anyway, good luck, and may the forces of evil become confused on the way to your house.

Comment: @VladPreda this is because the data array that `addAttribute` expects, gets passed through a `_prepareValues` method. This `_prepareValues` method expects 'visible' as the parameter option. It will then change the array key to 'is_visible' for that supplied parameter. This drives me crazy as well, but explains why it wasn't working for you. `updateAttribute` accepts the actual "code" for the attribute's configuration option you are looking to update.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it in this way.

Go to **Catalog** >> **Attributes** >> **Manage Attributes** >> **Add new attribute**

Then, save. Then, Go to database and Run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code ='attribute_code';
```

Change the column *frontend_input* value to hidden, then save.

Hope it helps.