# Products are not displaying on magento admin backend, but exists there

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working on a Magento and having an issue on admin section as product are not displaying. If I do inspect element, then I can see the products details as in hidden div folder.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
[screenshot of my localhost megento setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSlgK.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you go through all the settings of the product and every single setting in your store to make sure you don't have any type of hiding enabled? You're saying you can't see them on the backend or the frontend? So on which screen can you view them?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for you time. I'm unable to show the product on details page in admin section. How I can check whether hiding is enabled or not? I can view the product details on inspect element and making the hidden div to show.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make the products visible again is with a SQL query

```
find this somewhere: 'is_visible', '0'
```

You need to change is_visible to 1

reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14525869/1579789

Comment: I have found three tables:- 
fshcustomer_eav_attribute_website
fshcatalog_eav_attribute
fshcustomer_eav_attribute

Can you please tell me in which table I have to modify the data and for which attribute?

Comment: do you have any tables ending in _product? i'd say you would want to set all of those to visible if you can. There might be a way to do it through the UI.

Comment: There are number of tables are there in database having same name in ending. as https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojpswt47g2cutyt/hidden_pro2.png?dl=0

Comment: that's not a table, that's just an image. have you run a sql query before?

Comment: Yes I have. But I'm new in magento.

Comment: Are they possibly in a hidden category?

Comment: Under Catalog>Manage Products, are they enabled? What is their visibility set to?

Comment: maybe you can take a look at the settings in this demo store to see if any of yours are incorrect. http://demo.icebergcommerce.com/admin

Comment: Yes I can see the listing of all the products there.

Comment: So which section of the admin panel are the products not showing up?

Comment: After click on single product,it goes to product details page. So here the data is not displaying with the left panel tab eg General, Prices extra there is nothing is showing.

Comment: In the screenshot you provided, you're looking at the Pricing tab. General and Pricing appear to be displaying for you, along with a price. I'm still not sure what it is that's not showing up for you.